Как в pandas сохранить файл csv в нужном формате?
Как в pandas добавить в нужный формат файл csv?
Я делал таким образом:
allBs4gTable.to_csv('tempfile4g.csv', sep=',', index=False, header=False)

файл получил в таком формате:
MD,MD0461,MR1,MG069,46,3800,1

а хотелось бы в табличном формате получить. потому что при загрузке моего файла csv, получаю ошибку, что не верный формат


Как выглядит исходный Data Frame? (приведите вывод функции allBs4gTable.head()).
Как должен выглядеть сохранённый файл и что такое "в табличном формате"?
Кто ругается на "ошибку что не верный формат"? Приведите полный текст ошибки.


а что, по-вашему, такое "табличный формат"?

"при загрузке моего файла csv" - при загрузке куда? Если обратно в Pandas, то грузите с теми же параметрами sep и index, с какими записывали. Только header=False уберите при записи, иначе вы лишаетесь названий столбцов.

Для того чтобы сохранить DataFrame в CSV файл в табличном формате с заголовками и индексами, вам нужно убедиться, что параметры index и header установлены в True, если вам не нужны индексы, то поставьте значение False в index.
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Column1': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
    'Column2': ['Привет', 'я', 'написал', 'код', 'и', 'он', 'работает']
}

allBs4gTable = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Сохранение DataFrame в CSV файл с заголовками и индексами
allBs4gTable.to_csv('tempfile4g.csv', sep=',', index=True, header=True)


Мне кажется, он хочет потом ещё загрузить данные из csv-файла обратно в data frame.
